# Remove html tags and codes from string

Tags: php, html, sql

Hi I have this code in the database. How can I retrieve it and send it as text through php mail()? I have tried strip_lashes and it removed the `<p>` and other html tags but the html codes like `&#39;` still persists even when I  use php html_entity_decode...

```
<p>Thank you somebody&#39;s favourite .</p><p><br /><p>Tel: &nbsp12345678/ 8881456</p>
```

Comment: Is this database HTML is shown like a code to the mail? 
or you need to draw out the HTML structure to the mail?

Comment: I need to draw out the HTML structure and insert a new line whenever </p> is detected.

Comment: So just use the mime type as HTML for mail function, it will treat your text as an HTML content for sending mail and send on structure that you provided

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [strip_tags()](https://www.php.net/strip_tags) function to remove HTML tags, and the [html_entity_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function to replace HTML entities with their respective characters.

```
$string = "<p>Thank you somebody&#39;s favourite .</p><p><br /><p>Tel: &nbsp12345678/ 8881456</p>";
$formatted = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string));
```

Outputs:

```
Thank you somebody's favourite .Tel:  12345678/ 8881456
```

Comment: trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string))); to remove unneeded <head> tag newlines, if you are decoding entire html page (eg newsletter)

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the message from the database and store it as it is in the $message variable then
your mail function should be like this:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

With the $headers variable like this:

```
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" . 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

(The $headers variable should be defined before the mail function)

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP strip_tags function :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

just use the mime type as HTML for mail function, it will treat your text as an HTML content for sending mail and send on structure that you provided.